# [ character in powershell

Tags: scripting, powershell

I'm using Powershell for replace a string in a text file.

For replace *String 1* to *String 2* in *file.txt* I use

```
(Get-Content file.ps1) | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace 'String 1', 'String 2'} | Set-Content file.txt
```

It works pretty well even with for replace characters like *-* and *#*

It need to replace a string with the *[* character but it doesn't work. I need to replace *-state [VMstate]::stopped* with *-state stopped* but it doesn't work with

```
(Get-Content TEMP_config.ps1) | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '-state [VMstate]::stopped', '-state stopped'} | Set-Content TEMP_config.ps1
```

How can i find the **[** char?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The replace [operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347588.aspx) uses [regular expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315294.aspx) to match text. One way  to search for literal text is to escape the search text:

```
$search = [regex]::escape('[MyText]')
(Get-Content file.ps1) | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace $search , 'String 2'} | Set-Content file.txt
```

Comment: @RicardoPolo Glad you found this useful. If you don't mind, please take a second to mark the answer you found that solved your problem as the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to escape the `[`:

```
$_ -replace '-state \[VMstate]::stopped', '-state stopped'
```

Or use `[Regex]::escape` if you are not sure what to escape

Answer (score 2):

You can use "\[" instead of "[" (prefixed with a backslash) to escape the [ character